# Target flash 10.3 with Flex 4.6

Tags: flash, flex4, flash-builder

How would i go about compiling a Flex 4.6 Project for Flash Player 10.3 ?

In the Flex compiler settings, I have set the additional compiler arguments:
-target-player=10.3.0 -swf-version=12

And I added the 10.3 playerglobal.swc

Here are my settings (I cannot change the "Adobe Flash Player options"):

[image: Flex Compiler Settings]

But the resulting swf still requires Flash 11.1.

Am I missing something or do Flex 4.6 Projects not compile to Flash 10.3?
I have been using Flex 4.1 previously and didn't add any Flex 4.6 specific components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Change the Adobe Flash Player options from `Use minimum version required by the Flex SDK` to `Use a specific version`: 10.3.0

Now it gets a little tricky...

Flash Builder will say

> "The currently selected Flex SDK requires a minimum Adobe Flash Player
>   version 11.1.0"

This means:
If you want to use Flex 4.6, you HAVE to use Flash Player 11 (just like Flash Builder told you). You may NOT target FP 10.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Problem is that Flex won't let me change the settings. If i use the specific version, flex says: "The currently selected Flex SDK requires a minimum Adobe Flash Player version 11.1.0" and greys out "Apply" and "OK". See here: http://i43.tinypic.com/280pieh.jpg

Comment: "The currently selected Flex SDK requires a minimum" doesn't that  answer your question?

Comment: well asMan, i was pretty sure that there was a manual override mode with the command line switches, but you had to make sure not to use any FP11 features sich as molehill. I guess not: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ee0.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to remove the default Air SDK playerglobal.swc from

Project -> Properties -> ActionScript Build Path -> Library Path

and add the specific playerGlobal SWC version (10.3 in this case). You should then be able to set the 'Use specific version to 10.3.

However, you may get errors such as -  *VerifyError: Error #1079: Native methods are not allowed in loaded code* - if you try to use features not supported by that version of the player